# ExtJS 6 - Different parameters for build and development environments

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a Config.js file in which I store some general configuration parameters, in this case, a webservice url for the stores to consume services. I would like to have the same parameter with different values depending on the environment, development and production.

This is my current config file:

```
Ext.define('MyProjectName.Config', {

   singleton : true,

   config : {
      webserviceType: 'ajax',
      urls : {
         webserviceBaseUrl: 'myDevelopmentOrProductionURLHere'
      },
      services: {
        login: 'login',
        ...
      }
      ...
```

And this is how I use this configuration in the stores:

```
Ext.define('MyProjectName.store.Login', {

   extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
   alias: 'store.login',
   ...

   proxy: {
      type: MyProjectName.Config.config.webserviceType,
      url: MyProjectName.Config.getUrls().webserviceBaseUrl + MyProjectName.Config.getServices().login
   },
  ...
```

For example, I would like to point to localhost as webservice url for development build and an internet url for production build.

Comment: Found a related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098699/deploy-same-javascript-webapp-build-to-different-environments?rq=1